# how to increase 16 character limit to display user name in Terminal / UNIX?

Tags: command-line, unix, ls, username

I have several Mac users attached to my NAS whose usernames exceed the 16 char user display (ie SportsFreelancer01), so under the ls -al command, it shows up as user "SportsFreelancer", without #. Is there a way to set the default display to more than 16? Say 24 or 36 (or any)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple names that are the same (SportsFreelancer01, SportsFreelancer02, etc.) You could use the -n option, which would display numbers instead of names.

If you really want the names, try setting LS_COLWIDTHS to 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0.  The 4th 0 is the user name; you might try a 64 or 32 in there.

Comment: Is this in a pref somewhere? can I set it for all sessions, or is it session specific?

Comment: you could put it in your .bashrc.  Test first though by just setting on the command line  i.e. export LS_COLWIDTHS="0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0"

Comment: looks like my Mac OS X 10.6.8 has dynamic display on by default. My affected system is an Isilon running OneFS...root runs zsh. Running export does not change display (command executes tho)